# Difficulty drawing shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, quartz-core

I'm attempting to create a custom shadow for a UIView using UIBezierPath. I want it to be a slanted shadow, though I'm having difficulty drawing the custom path.

```
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0f, 10.0f);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

CGFloat shadowDepth = 20.0;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, shadowDepth)];
[path stroke];

self.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```

The shadow does not show up. When I simply set the path of the shadow to be around the border of the view, the shadow shows correctly. **Therefore, I must be drawing the bezier path incorrectly.** Any ideas?

This works:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a closed path.  You don't need to stroke it.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
CGFloat xMax = CGRectGetMaxX(bounds);
CGFloat yMax = CGRectGetMaxY(bounds);
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.x + shadowDepth, bounds.y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xMax + shadowDepth, bounds.y)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xMax, yMax)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(bounds.x, yMax)];
[path closePath];
self.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```